# SQL exists returns all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a mailing list and there are many entries that are duplicates. I'm trying to find the duplicates so I can remove them. When I run the full query below I get all of the items in the table (142,000 +). When I run the subquery I get only 5768 rows. I need all the columns for each duplicate row to decide which one gets deleted. What am I doing wrong that causes the full query to return all the rows?

```
select * from Mailinglist
where exists
(select count(*), mailaddress, CenterName
from Mailinglist
group by MailAddress, CenterName
having count(*)>1)
```

Comment: Why not just run the inner query? The one that has the `Having` clause?

Comment: @codingbiz sub query has your result, delete duplicated except one, because you need at-least one data after deletion , right, you can use 'offset 2 fetch next 100 rows' mehtod

Comment: Subquery is not related to the outer query - that's why it returns all rows from outer query.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do it this way:

```
select t1.*, t2.cnt 
from Mailinglist t1
join (
  select count(*) as cnt, mailaddress, CenterName
  from Mailinglist
  group by MailAddress, CenterName
  having count(*)>1
) t2 ON t1.MailAddress = t2.MailAddress and t1.CenterName = t2.CenterName
```

Using `EXISTS` just checks for the existence, or not, of records: if the subquery returns one or more records, then `EXISTS` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

`EXISTS` returns true if there is even a single record in the query following it.
What you are looking for is

```
select * from Mailinglist
where mailaddress IN 
(
    select mailaddress
    from Mailinglist
    group by MailAddress, CenterName
    having count(*)>1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `EXISTS` returns true if the subquery returns a row. Your subquery,
is returning one or more rows, and thus returning `TRUE` for the `EXISTS` condition.

To get the `MailingList` with duplicates, you can just run the subquery:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    mailaddress,
    CenterName
FROM Mailinglist
GROUP BY
    MailAddress, CenterName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

To delete the duplicates, you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MailAddress, Centername ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM MailingList
)
DELETE FROM Cte WHERE rn > 1
```

Just replace the `ORDER BY` clause depending on which row of the duplicates you want to retain.

Answer (score 0):

There's no filtering (where) in your subquery so it will allways result something.

```
SELECT        *
FROM            Mailinglist AS ML
WHERE        EXISTS
        (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Expr1, mailaddress, CenterName
        FROM            Mailinglist AS CNT
        WHERE        (ML.MailAddress = CNT.MailAddress) AND (ML.CenterName = CNT.CenterName)
        GROUP BY mailaddress, CenterName
        HAVING         (COUNT(*) > 1))
```